# Tree shakeable static methods (using rxjs and lodash in alongside)

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, rxjs, lodash

I want to use `rxjs` and `lodash` or `ramda` in the same project.
I am using typescript with ECMAScript module import statements. (In an ionic project with `webpack` as the module bundler)

`rxjs` and `lodash-es` propagate import statements like this, to enable tree shaking:

```
import { map } from 'lodas-es'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators
```

As you can see, this approach has two problems:
Name clashes (I could use an alias, but I think this will lead to more confusion)
Very general method names like `map`, `filter` etc. are in both libraries present and you always have to look in the import statement, which one is meant and where it came from.

The static method approach is much more readable in my opinion, because it is so explicit.
I want to keep the syntax like it is in commonjs and also enable tree-shaking. Is this possible somehow? Which alternatives do I have here?

```
// commonjs
const _ = require('lodash')
const Rx = require('rxjs')

_.filter()
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3]).pipe(Rx.filter())

// esmodule (this does not work, but I would like to use it this way,
// with tree shaking enabled)
import _ from 'lodash'
import Rx from 'rxjs'
```

Comment: I am not sure if this prevents tree-shaking, but you can do `import * as Rx from 'rxjs'` and `import * as _ from 'lodash'`, and access functions with `Rx.map(...)` and `_.map(...)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure "god objects" like `_` and `Rx` are exactly what prevents tree shaking.

Comment: Use aliases.  It is not confusing if you choose sensible aliases.  How about `import {map as _map} from "lodas-es";` and `import {map as rxmap} from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: On the other hand: Importing lodash if you already use RxJS seems counterproductive if your goal is to minimize size. `map` is even built in JavaScript btw.

Comment: @Brandon If I wanted to prevent confusion, I had to use aliases everywhere in the project and force my team to do so. This is not practical at all.

Comment: Rxjs is a FRP and lodash/ramda is a FP library. I don't like the idea of using Observables everywhere, just because I want my project to be in a pure functional style. There are only little standard implementations of functional concepts built into the language, they are not enough to work in a functional style. I think i need both libraries ...
Thanks for your comments! :)

Comment: I've aliased it as `import { filter as rx_filter} from 'rxjs/operators'` and manually created a _namespace_ `$`; `const $ = { filter: rx_filter }`, and use it as `$.filter` Not a solution but a workaround.

Comment: In such a case, I would create a file that re-exports all used lodash-functions under a different name using `export {map as _map} from 'lodash'`, and then add an eslint rule `no-restricted-imports` to forbid using lodash directly, but always use my file instead.